# Laptop won't start

Tags: mac, troubleshooting, macbook-pro

My macbook pro won't turn on. There's just no power... nothing. When I put the charger in, it acts strangely. The orange light sometimes turns into green. My laptop is new, so I highly doubt there is something very wrong with it. What could be wrong?

Comment: a Mac Pro is something very different to a macbook pro ;)

Also, that sounds like there really IS something very wrong with it (the light is supposed to ALWAYS be green. push the little button on the left side down near the front to check if the battery has any charge) and how new is new?

Comment: mine is orange when charging, green when charged

Comment: sorry i meant a macbook pro

Comment: i don't see any button on the left side near the front... when i click the button on the bottom, two green lights appear, but then they dissapear

Comment: Is this one of the MBP's with the integrated battery?

Comment: yes, i believe so. I can take the battery out if I want to. I think there may be something wrong with the rechargeable battery?

Comment: Then that's not an integrated battery. See my answer below.

Comment: Oh, I assumed it was a NEW new laptop (as in, the 2010 revision MBP's)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the battery out and try to start it up.

(See comments - user noted that the laptop had a removable battery (also not that new))

Comment: Why did that work?

Comment: You're probably going to need a new battery.

Comment: it's running out of juice?

Comment: Batteries do weird things sometimes. For example, the battery in my personal MBP stopped working and swelled to 1.2 times its size, putting pressure on the glass trackpad and breaking it. I've worked with thousands of MBPs and never experienced that before. Weird things happen with them. If you can, take it into an Apple store and have them test it before buying a new one.

Comment: @melee: exactly same thing here, swollen battery is a known MBP problem. I guess there was a batch of bad batteries, or either there's something wrong in the production process.

Comment: @stijn: they almost didn't replace it under AppleCare. I was pretty upset.

Comment: Might also be static buildup.  With the battery out, unplug everything and hold the power button down for 30+ seconds.  Replace the battery and plug it back up and it might work.

Comment: @melee; I too was a victim of a swollen battery :( unfortunately now being outside of the recall period I had to fork out the cash for a new one.!

Comment: If the machine is still within warranty, Apple should replace faulty batteries for free - as long as the duty cycle is under 300.