# Laptop won't start

Tags: apache-http-server, macos, troubleshooting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Laptop won't start](https://superuser.com/questions/201186/laptop-wont-start)

My mac pro won't turn on. There's just no power... nothing. When I put the charger in, it acts strangely. The orange light sometimes turns into green. My laptop is new, so I highly doubt there is something very wrong with it. What could be wrong?

Comment: This is a better question for [superuser](http://www.superuser.com) but I'll ask the obvious: do you have it plugged into AC or are you trying to run off the battery?

Comment: by AC do you mean plugging in the charger?

Answer (score 1):

If your Mac*book* Pro is new why don't you call Apple, it'll still be under support, you'll have to do this anyway if it's dead. Oh and please read our FAQ next time as this question is more appropriate for our sister site superuser.com.